# How to get the downloaded file name? (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

HTML code:

```
<a target="_blank" class="truncate-text" id="rfq-display-attachment-0">
          BEHR SDS.pdf
        </a>
```

I am downloading this link:

```
link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='rfq-display-attachment-0']")
filename = link1.text
link1.click()
```

According to this, the filename will be `BEHR SDS.pdf` But after downloading the file, the filename of the downloaded file is `BEHR SDS.1637344008787.pdf`. Here the name in the text and the actual filenames are different.

How to get the accurate filename in this case? I don't want the text of the `<a>` tag?

Comment: You can take the text and then replace the name of the downloaded file

Comment: how to replace?? renaming the file in the download directory?

Comment: Yes, that's what I can think of. Let me know if you are interested in that solution, I can provide you the answer.

Comment: I don't think its possible, because this code goes through many loops and also there are `try except` blocks, if this link is not found , i have set as ` ` empty string.

Comment: I think trimming the `.1637344008787` part is enough since every file name has this type of part only.

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP comment above that,

```
I think trimming the .1637344008787 part is enough since every file name has this type of part only.
```

You can do the following:

```
a = "BEHR SDS.1637344008787.pdf"
orginal_file_name = a.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'
print(orginal_file_name)
```

Now I have hardcoded the file name, you should go to directory and look for the latest file which has been downloaded.